# GeoTools modify a FeatureType to change its name

Tags: postgis, java, geotools

I have a featureCollection and I want to save it into `PostGIS` dataStore. So I'm going to create a database table by geotools. I want to name my table "ali". But I can't rename the schema!

```
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureCollection collection=...;
SimpleFeatureType schema = collection.getSchema();
SimpleFeatureType schema2 = DataUtilities.createSubType(schema,null,null,"ali",null);
dataStore.createSchema(schema2); // but it creates with name "polygon"
```

How can I rename the schema to create a table with my desired name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `null` inputs of the `createSubType` function.
If you have a glance at the `DataUtilities#createSubType` you will see:

```
public static SimpleFeatureType createSubType(SimpleFeatureType featureType,
        String[] properties, CoordinateReferenceSystem override, String typeName, URI namespace)
        throws SchemaException {

    if ((properties == null) && (override == null)) {
        return featureType;
    }
    ....
}
```

It shows that the featuretype will not change with null inputs.

[DataUtilitis.java github](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/DataUtilities.java)

---

You can make your own function like this:

```
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

public class MyUtil {

  public static SimpleFeatureType createWithNewName(SimpleFeatureType featureType, String newTypeName) {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder tb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    tb.setName(newTypeName);
    tb.setNamespaceURI(featureType.getName().getNamespaceURI());
    tb.setCRS(featureType.getCoordinateReferenceSystem()); // not interested in warnings from this simple method
    tb.addAll(featureType.getAttributeDescriptors());
          tb.setDefaultGeometry(featureType.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName());
    return tb.buildFeatureType();
  }
}
```